# Ant did not compile the resources, i cannot log using log4j

Tags: java, logging, ant, log4j

When running a java app project through ant, ant is looking for log4j properties,

can someone help me on how can i include the resources/log4j.properties into compilation of my project so i can use log4j

here's my build.xml

```
<property name="maven.repo.local" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository" />


<target name="clean">
    <echo message="deleting directory build" />
    <delete dir="build" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <echo message="creating directory build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <echo message="compiling source codes" />
    <javac srcdir="src" classpathref="jars" includeantruntime="false" destdir="build/classes" />

</target>

<target name="jar" depends="clean,compile">
    <echo message="creating a Jar fire, using compiled classes from build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="build/jar" />


    <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.sample.anttutorial.Main" />
        </manifest>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${maven.repo.local}" includes="log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar" />
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true" />

</target>

<path id="jars">
    <fileset dir="${maven.repo.local}" includes="log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar" />
</path>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your log4j.properties :

```
# Log format to Ant Build
log4j.logger.org.apache.tools.ant=info, antout
log4j.additivity.org.apache.tools.ant=false
log4j.appender.antout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.antout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.antout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d]\t%m%n
log4j.appender.antout.File=${catalina.home}/logs/AntBuild.out
```

in your code you can define :

```
    Project p = new Project(); 
    Log4jListener log4jListener = new Log4jListener();
    p.addBuildListener(log4jListener);
```